# How can I fix Unicode issues in the dataset returned from my SPARQL query?

Tags: unicode, sparql, dbpedia

At the moment, I am getting rows with Unicode decode issues, while using SPARQL on Dbpedia (using Virtuoso servers). This is an example of what I am getting Knut %C3%85ngstr%C3%B6m.
The right name is Knut Ångström. Cool, now how do I fix this? My crafted query is:

```
select distinct (strafter(str(?influencerString),str(dbpedia:)) as ?influencerString) (strafter(str(?influenceeString),str(dbpedia:)) as ?influenceeString) where {
  { ?influencer a dbpedia-owl:Person . ?influencee a dbpedia-owl:Person .
    ?influencer dbpedia-owl:influenced ?influencee .
    bind( replace( str(?influencer), "_", " " ) as ?influencerString )
    bind( replace( str(?influencee), "_", " " ) as ?influenceeString )
}
  UNION
  { ?influencee a dbpedia-owl:Person . ?influencer a dbpedia-owl:Person .
    ?influencee dbpedia-owl:influencedBy ?influencer .
    bind( replace( str(?influencee), "_", " " ) as ?influenceeString )
    bind( replace( str(?influencer), "_", " " ) as ?influencerString )
}
}
```

Comment: What query produced the result?  Please note that "Questions concerning problems with code you've written **must describe the specific problem — and include valid code to reproduce it** — in the question itself."  In this case, you might provide a query that we can paste into the [DBpedia SPARQL endpoint](http://dbpedia.org/sparql).

Comment: I have supplied the query.

Comment: I am stuck with solving this since a day, but to no avail.

Comment: http://html-codes.net/html/url-decode/

Comment: @HansPassant: Thank you. A manual approach, but good. I am looking for a more SPARQL related approach that does the trick, but nice. Moreover, I have 30000 lines, the site you mentioned fails to handle that much and throws an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The DBpedia wiki explains that the identifiers for resources in the English DBpedia dataset use URIs, not IRIs, which means that you'll end up with encoding issues like this.

> ### [3. Denoting or Naming “things”](http://dbpedia.org/Datasets#h338-3)
>
> Each thing in the DBpedia data set is denoted by a de-referenceable
>   IRI- or URI-based reference of the form
>   http://dbpedia.org/resource/Name, where Name is derived from the URL
>   of the source Wikipedia article, which has the form
>   http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name. Thus, each DBpedia entity is tied
>   directly to a Wikipedia article. Every DBpedia entity name resolves to
>   a description-oriented Web document (or Web resource).
>
> Until DBpedia release 3.6, we only used article names from the English
>   Wikipedia, but since DBpedia release 3.7, we also provide localized
>   datasets that contain IRIs like http://xx.dbpedia.org/resource/Name,
>   where xx is a Wikipedia language code and Name is taken from the
>   source URL, http://xx.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name.
>
> Starting with DBpedia release 3.8, we use IRIs for most DBpedia entity
>   names. IRIs are more readable and generally preferable to URIs, but
>   for backwards compatibility, we still use URIs for DBpedia resources
>   extracted from the English Wikipedia and IRIs for all other languages.
>   Triples in Turtle files use IRIs for all languages, even for English.
>
> There are several details on the encoding of URIs that should always
>   be taken into account.

In this particular case, it looks like you don't really need to break up the identifier so much as get a label for the entity.

```
## If things were guaranteed to have just one English label, 
## we could simply take ?xLabel as the value that we want with
## `select ?xLabel { … }`, but since there might be more than 
## one, we can group by `?x` and then take a sample from the
## set of labels for each `?x`.

select (sample(?xLabel) as ?label) {
  ?x dbpedia-owl:influenced dbpedia:August_Kundt ;
     rdfs:label ?xLabel .
  filter(langMatches(lang(?xLabel),"en"))
}
group by ?x
```

[SPARQL results](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http://dbpedia.org&query=##%20If%20things%20were%20guaranteed%20to%20have%20just%20one%20English%20label,%20%0D%0A##%20we%20could%20simply%20take%20?xLabel%20as%20the%20value%20that%20we%20want%20with%0D%0A##%20%60select%20?xLabel%20%7B%20%E2%80%A6%20%7D%60,%20but%20since%20there%20might%20be%20more%20than%20%0D%0A##%20one,%20we%20can%20group%20by%20%60?x%60%20and%20then%20take%20a%20sample%20from%20the%0D%0A##%20set%20of%20labels%20for%20each%20%60?x%60.%0D%0A%0D%0Aselect%20%28sample%28?xLabel%29%20as%20?label%29%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20?x%20dbpedia-owl%3ainfluenced%20dbpedia%3aAugust_Kundt%20;%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20rdfs%3alabel%20?xLabel%20.%0D%0A%20%20filter%28langMatches%28lang%28?xLabel%29,%22en%22%29%29%0D%0A%7D%0D%0Agroup%20by%20?x&format=text/html&timeout=30000&debug=on)

Simplifying your query a bit, we can have this:

```
select
  (sample(?rLabel) as ?influencerName)
  (sample(?eLabel) as ?influenceeName)
where {
  ?influencer dbpedia-owl:influenced|^dbpedia-owl:influencedBy ?influencee .
  dbpedia-owl:Person ^a ?influencer, ?influencee .

  ?influencer rdfs:label ?rLabel .
  filter( langMatches(lang(?rLabel),"en") )

  ?influencee rdfs:label ?eLabel .
  filter( langMatches(lang(?eLabel),"en") )
}
group by ?influencer ?influencee
```

[SPARQL results](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http://dbpedia.org&query=select%0D%0A%20%20%28sample%28?rLabel%29%20as%20?influencerName%29%0D%0A%20%20%28sample%28?eLabel%29%20as%20?influenceeName%29%0D%0Awhere%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20?influencer%20dbpedia-owl%3ainfluenced%7C%5Edbpedia-owl%3ainfluencedBy%20?influencee%20.%0D%0A%20%20dbpedia-owl%3aPerson%20%5Ea%20?influencer,%20?influencee%20.%0D%0A%20%20%0D%0A%20%20?influencer%20rdfs%3alabel%20?rLabel%20.%0D%0A%20%20filter%28%20langMatches%28lang%28?rLabel%29,%22en%22%29%20%29%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20?influencee%20rdfs%3alabel%20?eLabel%20.%0D%0A%20%20filter%28%20langMatches%28lang%28?eLabel%29,%22en%22%29%20%29%0D%0A%7D%0D%0Agroup%20by%20?influencer%20?influencee%0D%0A&format=text/html&timeout=30000&debug=on)

If you don't want language tags on those results, then add a call to `str()`:

```
select
  (str(sample(?rLabel)) as ?influencerName)
  (str(sample(?eLabel)) as ?influenceeName)
where {
  ?influencer dbpedia-owl:influenced|^dbpedia-owl:influencedBy ?influencee .
  dbpedia-owl:Person ^a ?influencer, ?influencee .

  ?influencer rdfs:label ?rLabel .
  filter( langMatches(lang(?rLabel),"en") )

  ?influencee rdfs:label ?eLabel .
  filter( langMatches(lang(?eLabel),"en") )
}
group by ?influencer ?influencee
```

[SPARQL results](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http://dbpedia.org&query=select%0D%0A%20%20%28str%28sample%28?rLabel%29%29%20as%20?influencerName%29%0D%0A%20%20%28str%28sample%28?eLabel%29%29%20as%20?influenceeName%29%0D%0Awhere%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20?influencer%20dbpedia-owl%3ainfluenced%7C%5Edbpedia-owl%3ainfluencedBy%20?influencee%20.%0D%0A%20%20dbpedia-owl%3aPerson%20%5Ea%20?influencer,%20?influencee%20.%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20?influencer%20rdfs%3alabel%20?rLabel%20.%0D%0A%20%20filter%28%20langMatches%28lang%28?rLabel%29,%22en%22%29%20%29%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20?influencee%20rdfs%3alabel%20?eLabel%20.%0D%0A%20%20filter%28%20langMatches%28lang%28?eLabel%29,%22en%22%29%20%29%0D%0A%7D%0D%0Agroup%20by%20?influencer%20?influencee&format=text/html&timeout=30000&debug=on)

Comment: Good one, but don't want " "  and @en. It's unnecessary and makes my life harder when I am writing a parser.

Comment: What do you mean that you don't want `" "`?  I don't see any `" "` in the result.  If you want a plain literal, then just take the `str()` of the thing.  These are pretty basic SPARQL functions at this point…  Anyhow, I've updated the answer to show how to strip language tags.  In both cases, the results are strings;  you shouldn't be parsing the tabular output that comes out from the endpoint;  if you need to process it mechanically, then make sure you're pulling down the XML or JSON or RDF or some other machine readable output format.

Comment: Ah, I think I see what you mean.  In the tabular output that the endpoint renders, strings with language tags are printed as `"string content"@lang`.  Plain literals (strings without a datatype or language tag) were just printed as `content` (without quotes).  Both were literals though;  if you're processing this output with code, then you should get the results in a machine readable format (e.g., XML or RDF).  XML or RDF APIs will make it easy to get the value that you want.  The original query is still in my answer, though;  I _updated_ the answer with the additional query.

Comment: Many thanks again Joshua. I have finalized the process and it works perfectly fine with my non-shorthand SPARQL query. I appreciate your assistance in fixing this issue. I was also wondering if there was a way to actually use SPARQL to actually create nodes.csv and edges.csv files without using Java for parsing, but that's beyond the scope. I am using Java anyway.

Comment: Are you using an RDF/SPARQL library in Java? Getting the string values from the results of your query would be trivial if you're using, e.g., [tag:jena].  Unless there's some particular reason for it, getting the results as CSV and parsing them manually seems like that might be better spent elsewhere (but I don't know the specific scenario, so maybe there is some reason for it).